# plt.suptitle : TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

This piece of code is working at one place but throwing error at another place not sure why i am encountering this below error:

**plt.suptitle plt.suptitle(dataset.columns[i] + ' (xyz)', fontsize=10)**

**TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataset = df
dfsize = dataset[df.columns[0]].size
x = []
for i in range(dfsize):
    x.append(i)

dataset.shape
# dataset.dropna(inplace=True)
dataset.columns.values
var = ""
for i in range(dataset.shape[1]):  ## 1 is for column, dataset.shape[1] calculate length of col

    y = dataset[dataset.columns[i]].values
    y = y.astype(float)
    y = y.reshape(-1, 1)
    y.shape
    from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

    missingvalues = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean', verbose=0)
    missingvalues = missingvalues.fit(y)
    y = missingvalues.transform(y[:, :])

    from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
    from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

    labelencoder_x = LabelEncoder()
    x = labelencoder_x.fit_transform(x)

    from scipy.interpolate import *

    p1 = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
    # from matplotlib.pyplot import *
    import matplotlib
    matplotlib.use('Agg')
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    plt.figure()
    plt.xticks(x, months, rotation=25,fontsize=8)
    plt.suptitle(dataset.columns[i] + ' (xyz)', fontsize=10)
```

i think my issue is coming due to wrong dataframe:

working dataframe is:

```
in               month   
AM               April         NaN
                 February    100.0
                 January      99.0
```

wrong dataframe:

```
                                  Verify the countDays
Assign                  month                         
AD                      April                    48.86
                        February                  4.76
                        January                  14.70
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
plt.suptitle(dataset.columns[i] + ' (xyz)', fontsize=10)
```

To:

```
plt.suptitle(dataset.columns[i] + ('xyz',), fontsize=10)
```

Comment: thanks yes it passed that stage, however, it stuck at another place like: var = var + "," + dataset.columns[i]

Answer (score 0):

i had to do some unprofessional way to solve this issue and by doing the following way it solved. However, i would like to know if there is some good way to do this.

I tried removing the first row but datafarme was so bad that i do not know why first row was not getting deleted and it was having some weired behaviour.

```
dff3=dff.groupby(['Assign','month'])[['Verify the countDays']].mean().round(decimals=2)
dff4=dff.groupby(['Assign','month'])[['Verify the countDays']].mean().round(decimals=2)
dff5=(dff3['Verify the countDays']/dff3['Verify the countDays'])+(dff3['Verify the countDays'])
```